Vcenter Datastore Reclaim Unallocated Space from Vm
I am using vcenter 6.7. By entering the settings of a VM from the panel, I manually changed the 300GB space reserved for HDD1 to 400GB.
Then, when I went to this server and looked, I saw that there was 100GB Unallocated Space. But I couldn't use it to Extend the C drive.
Then, in the Disk Management area on the same server, I right-clicked on the C drive and made Shrink Volume, and I regained 100GB of space from there.
In total, there were 2 Unallocated Spaces of 100 GB each.
I want to return these Unallocated Space to Vcenter Datastore.
Is there a best practice on this subject? How can I do that?


You have a recovery partition preventing you from extending the C: volume; this is unfortunately a common occurrence, because Windows setup used to place the recovery partition at the end of the disk (now it knows better and places it before the system volume).
See here for more info and solutions: https://superuser.com/questions/1354574/how-to-expand-the-windows-partition-when-the-recovery-one-is-in-the-way.
That said, there is no way to shrink a VMware virtual disk; you can only expand it.
If the disk is thin provisioned, its size does not really matter, because only the used space is actually consumed on the datastore; if it's thick provisioned, it will consume its full size.
If the disk is thick provisioned and you want to convert it to thin, you can do that by performing a storage vmotion to a different datastore and changing the disk type; there is no out-of-the-box way to convert it in place.
If you don't have another datastore available, there are several workarounds, but they are a bit more complex.

Actually, I gave up on expanding. My main problem right now is that I want to return these 100GB spaces, which are Unallocated Space on this server, to Vcenter Datastore.

See edited answer.

I checked the disk via Vcenter and it appears to be Thin provisioned. If I understand correctly, the fact that there is 200GB of unallocated space on this server is not reflected in the space shown as Used: 3.14 TB in the Datastore properties on Vcenter. But when I go into Vm properties, I see that 400GB is reserved for Hard Disk 1. This confuses me a bit.

This should help: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc/GUID-8204A8D7-25B6-4DE2-A227-408C158A31DE.html. Bottom line: on a thin provisioned virtual disk, empty space doesn't consume real space on the datastore.

I understood the working mechanism. But I wonder this. What data do Vcenter Datastore Capacity descriptions show? For example, let's say we have 10TB of total space. Let 5TB be shown as in use. If I increase and confirm a Thin Provisioned disk currently installed in any VM by 1TB via Vcenter, but it remains as Unallocated Space in the server, will the value shown as in use in the Vcenter Datastore settings start to be shown as 6TB while it is 5TB? Or do I still see 5TB of used space here because it is not used yet?
